# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to ClassName

Tags: object, observable, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

The Api which I used to handle the two response of the Api with o using retrofit and rxjava. I'm Creating the response model and error model.
I don't know how to handle both the responce in one Api here is my Implementation

```
@POST("login/")
Observable<Response<Object>> login(@Body LoginParamModel model);
```

so here is my api implementation

```
 RetroClient.getClient(ApiEndPointInterface.URl).create(ApiEndPointInterface.class)
            .login(model).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<Response<Object>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<Object> loginDataModelResponse) {
                    mLoginDataModelResponse=loginDataModelResponse;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    mLoginView.LoginError(e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    if (mLoginDataModelResponse.code() == 200 || mLoginDataModelResponse.code() == 201) {


                        LoginDataModel loginDataModel = (LoginDataModel) mLoginDataModelResponse.body();
                        mLoginView.LoginResult(loginDataModel);
                    } else if (mLoginDataModelResponse.code() == 400) {
                        try {
                            mLoginView.LoginError(CommonUtill.JsonReader(mLoginDataModelResponse.errorBody().string()));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

And I got success but the issue is I am Not Convert object class to Model Class

```
 LoginDataModel loginDataModel = (LoginDataModel) mLoginDataModelResponse.body();
```

I got this type of exception:

W: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.model.login.LoginDataModel

W: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.model.login.LoginDataModel

LoginDataModel is my Api Responce Model class and Here is RetroClientClass

```
public class RetroClient {
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
private Context mContext;

public static Retrofit getClient(String BaseUrl) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @NotNull
                @Override
                public Response intercept(@NotNull Chain chain) throws IOException {

                    String token = CommonUtill.ACCESS_TOKEN;
                    Request request = chain.request();

                    request = request.newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                            .addHeader("X-TOKEN-AUTHENTICATION", "True")
                            .build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            })
            .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();


    if (retrofit == null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

Comment: How is `ApiEndPointInterface` defined. Did you setup an RxJava adapter: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2#usage ?

Comment: @akarnokd plese check the updated code

Comment: Have you tried `Observable<Response<LoginDataModel>>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just Please change the ApiInterface

```
@POST("login/")
Observable<Response<LoginDataModel>> login(@Body LoginParamModel model);
```